# Revert to original Apple Boot Loader

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

Ok, I know that some of you may think that this is a stupid question, however, I would like to know how i can remove the GNU GRUB from my Macbook Air 2013?

What i did was the following: I tried to install Ubuntu on a MicroSD card as I had recently purchased one of the adapters that fit the SD card socket flush with the edge of the Mac. I followed some guides from the main website on how to convert the .iso to a .img.dmg file so that i could be extracted to a USB flash drive, which I then used to boot the "Live" version and then install Ubuntu on my MicroSD card. (Keep in mind, this was only done for experimental purposes.)

Now, however, every time when I start my Mac I get a black screen with a GNU GRUB title showing (when there is no MicroSD) and I just want to revert to the original boot loader but still be able to boot into Ubuntu whenever I want. Is that possible? If not, how do just get back to the original boot loader?

Thanks a lot and I'm sorry for the long text, I just wanted to make sure that everyone was on the same page.